# How to convert the array into string and check by alert() function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tostring

I want to create an array, convert it into a string, and display the array.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var instruments = ["guitar", "piano", "drum"];
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = instruments.toString();
    alert(typeof (instruments));
</script>
```

I want the alert gives the type of strings and print

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Array String</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var instruments = ["guitar", " piano", " drum"];
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = instruments.toString();
    alert(typeof (instruments));
</script>
    
 </html>
```

, but it pops up as object.

Comment: `instruments.toString()` is successfully giving you a string in return, but the array remains an array. If you want the string, you have to call `toString` on it every time - or, save it in a variable

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with this code for a while and finally come up with the answer that met my expected output. If there is anything that I can further improvise, please let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Array into String</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Array Into String Conversion</h1>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var instruments = ["Guitar", " Piano", " Drum"];
    var str = instruments.toString();

    document.write("Array into string = " + str);

    alert(typeof(str));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to perform a for loop to isolate each string of the array:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++)
    {  instruments.toString()  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 var instruments = ["guitar", "piano", "drum"];
 const string= instruments.join('');
 alert(string)
 console.log(string)
```

```js
 var instruments = ["guitar", "piano", "drum"];
 const string= instruments.join('');
 alert(instruments)
 console.log(string)
```